# Boost serialization (bug?) issue with MSVC, with vector<shared_ptr> in several libraries

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, shared-ptr

We use boost serialization in ours projects, both on linux (gcc) and Windows.
We encounter a problem only on Windows (for "every" versions of Windows (7 and 10) and of MSVC: Visual 2010 and 2015, ie. MSVC++ 10.0  _MSC_VER == 1600 or MSVC++ 14.0  _MSC_VER == 1900).

**Here is the problem summarized**, but I need to give more details after:
When I serialize a class

- which have base class
- and have 2 vector of shared_ptr of ClassB, with the same contents, and B inherits from the same base class

the serialization works, but the deserialization doesn't ("input stream error").
[image]

Yes, it's very strange:

- if I remove the base class, it works.
- if I inline the serialization code (empty function) of the base class, it works.
- if the 2 vectors don't have the same content, it works !!
- if I register the ClassBase in the serialize method of ClassTest, it works. I.e.:

  ```
  // in ClassTest:
  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
      ar.template register_type<ClassBase>();
      ...
  }
  ```

**Some details**

**When it works** on linux, and when it works on Windows with ClassBase type registration in the archive, we have the same xml output.
It's worth noting that:

- boost_serialization is version 17 on Windows and 9 on linux (I didn't tried to update boost on linux yet).
- On BaseClass xml tag, the tracking_level="1", so we have object_id.

**And when it doesn't work** (once again: the serialization of ClassTest is OK, but cannot deserialized "input stream error"):

- The main difference is in the serialization of ClassTest: the ClassBase part has no tracking_level.
- However it's not the only cause, because if the vectors are differents (same 2 first items, and a third item in one vector), tracking_level of ClassBase in ClassTest part is "0".

Last thing, if it can give you some clues: while we debugged our application, we noticed that the deserialization framework tries to deserialize a class into another.
It makes me think the serialization framework is confused about the classe types identifications.
Could it be a matter of dll linking? Of global static shared storage ?

I've posted a visual studio solution [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aoy4ax0S3ZS5gkxv1UIvRUd32oVO?e=ACVi4c).

Thanks a lot for your help. And if any clarification is needed, I'm available of course !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post here an answer if some have the same issue and are looking through this forum.
Thanks to boost developpers (you may read [this issue](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/issues/183)), the fix is to mark ClassBase as track_always:
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(ClassBase, boost::serialization::track_always)